Debugging slow operations using the MongoDB API and Oracle Autonomous JSON Database
I'm using the Oracle API for MongoDB with the Autonomous Database.  Some queries/aggregation pipelines aren't performing as well as I'd like.  How do I improve the performance?

Performance issues in this case are most often due to a missing index.  The best way to diagnose these issues is using Oracle SQL Monitoring.  Underneath the covers, the Oracle API for MongoDB translates all MongoDB commands to SQL operations.  You can specify a hint on MongoDB commands to generate a monitoring report for the underlying SQL.  This example assumes you are using mongosh to connect to the database.
Ensure you have the necessary roles.
From a SQL administrative user:
grant select on "V$SQL" to your_user;
grant select on "V$SQL_MONITOR" to your_user;
grant advisor to your_user; 
grant execute on dbms_sql_monitor to your_user;

Add the MONITOR hint
mongosh> db.movie.aggregate([{$match : {year:2000}}], {hint :{$native : "MONITOR"}});

or
mongosh> db.movie.find({$match : {year : 2000}}).hint({$native : "MONITOR"});

Determine the SQL_ID
The following query can be used to determine the SQL_ID of the command you just executed.
mongosh> db.aggregate([{$sql:`
       select sql_fulltext, sql_id 
       from v$sql 
       where sql_text like '%MONITOR%' and
             sql_text not like '%v$sql%'
       order by last_active_time desc
       fetch first 1 rows only
   `}]);
 [
   {
     SQL_FULLTEXT: '...',
     SQL_ID: '6xy9y446n1ha6'
   }
 ]

Generate the report
mongosh> var html = 
   db.aggregate([{$sql:`
     select dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor(
       sql_id => '6xy9y446n1ha6',
       report_level => 'ALL',
       type => 'ACTIVE'
     ) as "html"
     from dual
   `}]).toArray()[0].html;

mongosh> require('fs').writeFileSync('/Users/jspiegel/out.html', html);

Open the report
Open /Users/jspiegel/out.html in a web browser.
The report show detailed information including:

The SQL generated for the command
The runtime plan (e.g. index scan versus full table scan)
How much time was spent at each part of the plan
How many documents/rows were returned at each part of the plan


This is documented here
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/mongodb-api/mgapi/develop-applications-oracle-database-api-mongodb.html
